# Grep issue after escaping backslash

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I am trying to grep the string

```
"SNTCHDCS06-Filesystem D:\\ Label:Data  Serial Number f8271450"
```

from a csv file, but somehow I failed miserably.

I understand that I need to add two backlashes on top of the two backslashes (one for shell, one for bash), but it doesn't work after that.

The below command works.

```
[root@nagiospdc01 folder]# grep -e "^SNTCHDCS06-Filesystem D:\\\\" in/masterlist.csv
SNTCHDCS06-Filesystem D:\\ Label:Data  Serial Number f8271450,SNTCHDCS06,10.24.64.210,Active Directory,AD Server,UCS,Filesystem D:\\ Label:Data  Serial Number f8271450,Windows Team,0,XM_OPS_WIN,Windows Team,Y,Y,N,N,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,N,N,Y,Y,ITOC
```

When I try to grep for the space after that, grep doesn't work and simply fails.

```
[root@nagiospdc01 folder]# grep -e "^SNTCHDCS06-Filesystem D:\\\\ " in/masterlist.csv
```

Appreciate if someone can enlighten me on the correct grep syntax and command.

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes,

```
grep -e '^SNTCHDCS06-Filesystem D:\\ Label:Data Serial Number f8271450'
```

When using double quotes `\\` gets converted to a single `\` by bash. However bash does not look inside single quotes.

From the Bash manual:

> [3.1.2.2 Single Quotes](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html)
>
> Enclosing characters in single quotes (`'`) preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.
>
> [3.1.2.3 Double Quotes](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html)
>
> Enclosing characters in double quotes (`"`) preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of `$`, `` ` ``, `\`, and, when history expansion is enabled, `!`. The characters `$` and `` ` `` retain their special meaning within double quotes (see [Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions)). The backslash retains its special meaning only when followed by one of the following characters: `$`, `` ` ``, `"`, `\`, or newline. Within double quotes, backslashes that are followed by one of these characters are removed. Backslashes preceding characters without a special meaning are left unmodified. A double quote may be quoted within double quotes by preceding it with a backslash. If enabled, history expansion will be performed unless an `!` appearing in double quotes is escaped using a backslash. The backslash preceding the `!` is not removed.
>
> The special parameters `*` and `@` have special meaning when in double quotes (see [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)).

Answer (score 0):

The -F option in grep allows to search for fixed strings. Also the single quotes helps to search for the exact string.

-F, --fixed-strings : 
Interpret  PATTERN  as  a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.

```
grep -F 'SNTCHDCS06-Filesystem D:\\ Label:Data  Serial Number  f8271450' masterlist.csv

*SNTCHDCS06-Filesystem D:\\ Label:Data  Serial Number f8271450*
```